# Practicing melikah on a bird

Tags: halacha, korban, birds

Is there any prohibition to perform the method of melikah on a bird to practice or to learn how it was done in the mikdash?

Is it bal tashchis, or is it considered doing something productive such as learning and would be permitted?

Comment: If you sell it to a non-Jew then it's not wasting או מכור לנכרי

Comment: Maybe צער בעלי חיים

Comment: Why should this be different than practicing shechitah on an animal?

Comment: Shechita has a purpose its a lmaaseh limmud,melikah is only mikdash relevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA is that not only if anyway this bird will be killed? (but a nevaila is worth less then a shechuta, and if the bird was planned to be shechted, and you make it a nevaila is it not waisting a little bit?)

Comment: Someone has to know how to do it or we'll be in trouble!  If Mashiach comes towards the beginning of Nissan it will actually be pretty urgent - tzaraat is not so relevant and I don't know the statistics about zov for men or women, but most women have had children.  It will be very sad if the first Pesach in 2000 years can only be eaten by men (and young women, which makes it a little better, but still).

Comment: You could also practice on a treifah if you want.  Although I guess if it's weaker it might resist you less so it might not be as realistic.

Comment: @hazoriz ^^^ is a neveilah worth less than a treifah?  I doubt it, maybe when we have a beis hamikdash, but even then the tumah of bird neveilah is not so likely to practically do anything, since it only applies if you eat it which you can't do.

Comment: @Heshy most birds are not treif, where are you going to find treif birds?

Comment: @hazoriz personally I'm not planning to practice melikah any time soon (for me it's purely theoretical, I'm a Yisrael), but maybe a veterinarian who euthanizes sick animals?  The procedure they recommend here is actually very similar to melikah https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nwhc.usgs.gov/publications/field_manual/chapter_5.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiK4IWh-MvYAhXHkeAKHXDEDzEQFggmMAE&usg=AOvVaw32S15meGYA_A9zPkY5N9Qc